# How to unban a project on Maven

Tags: android, maven

I'm trying to install a file to my local Maven repositor (following the steps from https://gist.github.com/4211293), although, I'm always getting the following error message:

```
    PS C:\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib> mvn install:install-file  -DgroupId=com.google.android.gms -DartifactId=google-play-services-jar -Dversion=4 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=.\libs\google-play-services.jar
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building google-play-services 4
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) @ google-play-services ---
    [INFO] Installing C:\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib to C:\Users\Juliano\.m2\repository\com\google-play-services-jar\4\google-play-services-jar-4.jar
    [INFO]
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Skipping google-play-services
    [INFO] This project has been banned from the build due to previous failures.
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 1.534s
    [INFO] Finished at: Mon Dec 24 00:05:04 BRST 2012
    [INFO] Final Memory: 6M/89M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) on project google-play-services: Error installing artifact 'com:google-play-services-jar:jar': Failed to install artifact com:google-play-services-jar:jar:4: C:\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib
    (Access is denied) -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I'm not sure if the error is because google-play-services is being skipped, if you think so, please help to unban it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem solved. The error was related to the -Dfile parameter, as it seems to don't accept relative paths.

PS: Another problem I had was that I've been using PowerShell to run maven commands but there's some kind of incompatibility.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the `-Dfile` parameter you had before and the one you used that worked?

Comment: Adding quotes around the file name worked for me, instead of `-Dfile=shared.jar` I used `-Dfile="shared.jar"`

Answer (score 9):

To my knowledge, a project is only "banned" in that manner when some other module it depends on has failed to build. That's what it means about "previous failures". You need to go back to the first failure and fix that.

Comment: The problem is that google-play-services is already compiled by Google and the project I'm trying to install its file is compiling without errors.

Answer (score 6):

This error msg appears in maven, when you try to deploy the same release-version (not *-SNAPSHOT) to repository multiple times. That is generally forbidden, to prevent unpredictable builds. 
If you want to deploy the same version multiple times it needs to be -SNAPSHOT version.

I guess the same thing happens in your case, when you do install-file and the file already exists and is not a -SNAPSHOT version. 
Maven then concludes the install will fail again on any repeated attempts and therefore marks it as "banned".

Solution then, is to change artifact version to a -SNAPSHOT version or increase to next release-version - then build again.

Answer (score 0):

Problem:- If you are deploying your artifact with **maven deploy** plugin using "deploy-file" goal and error "this project has been banned from the build due to previous failures" occurs then following below is the solution.

Solution:- 1) make sure all required parameters are valid.
  
so check for white space.

2) -Dfile=target/artifactid is generated and found at correct place.

3) Durl=http://localhost:8081/nexus/repo have correct access.

Cheers